# How can I make a variable accessible to another class within the same project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable (`PrincipleIndex`) in a class (`Principles.cs`) in one C# project (`..\Bullseye\Biz Logic\Trading\Principle\Data\Principles.cs`).

```
int PrincipleIndex = Principles.Instance.RowIndexToPrincipleIndex(hti.Row);
```

1. `Principles` is a class with singleton design pattern
2. `RowIndexToPrincipleIndex(hti.Row)` - taking out row from a property grid

I want to make `PrincipleIndex` accessible to another class (`TradingCentralForm.cs`) within the same C# project, specifically, here:

```
principlesList.Select(p => p.GetInstanceForDatabase()).Where(p => p.Note == Principles.Instance[PrincipleIndex].Note).ToList()
```

However, `PrincipleIndex` is not accesible there.

I tried to make the variable `public` in `principle.cs` but it is not working. How can I properly make it accessible?

---

principle.cs:

```
internal class Principles
{
    #region Singelton

    private static readonly Principles instance;
    public static Principles Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
    static Principles()
    {
        instance = new Principles();
    }
    private Principles()
    {
        PrincipleIndicesTranslator.SetTranslatorMethod(UniqueName);
    }

    #endregion
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
private int principleIndex = 0;

public int PrincipleIndex 
{
    get { return principleIndex; }
}

...
    // this must be within the Principles class
    Principles.Instance.principleIndex = Principles.Instance.RowIndexToPrincipleIndex(hti.Row);
...
```