# how to access one class property in another class linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make an variable accessible to other class(within same csproj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442630/how-to-make-an-variable-accessible-to-other-classwithin-same-csproj)

I have a variable

```
int principleIndex = Principles.Instance.RowIndexToPrincipleIndex(hti.Row);
```

I want to use it in another class linq query:

```
principlesList.Select(p => p.GetInstanceForDatabase()).where(p=>p.principleIndex ).ToList()
```

but `principleIndex` is not accessible here.

How do I do it??? I tried to make it static and I also tried to use it inside a  property, but does not work.

Comment: Possibly a typo, but `principleIndex` != `principleindex` - check the casing of your variables.

Comment: yes that was a typing mistake , variable is same , please tell me how to do it

Comment: You need to show more code as this is not clear. What is `GetInstanceForDatabase()` returning?

Answer (score 0):

Is principleIndex defined in the same scope as your second line of code? If so perhaps your Where call should read something like .Where(forDBInstance => forDBInstance.Index == principleIndex)

Comment: either for Index  to appear in Linq wh have to create a proeprty in constructor , for that i have to updaete column in DB as well ... is there any other alternative

Comment: I think you'll have to post more code for us to understand the problem better.